# How to implement a search box like Google news

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a search box similar to what Google News. Basically when you type a search terms, you get two options in the drop down to allow you to search either in news or the whole web.

[image]

I know that there are many select plugins such as select2, but I don't really think that they are the right solution because they are designed for selecting options.

I would really appreciate it if someone can shed some light and point me to the right direction before I put something hacky. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried anything yet??

Comment: try Tokenfield for Bootstrap, it was easy for me to customize. To customize bind source property to external source.

Comment: @Gaurav I have tried to show/hide a list group which is placed right below the search input when user start typing. I also looked at select2 and tried to fix the options. Both feel very hacky. I am looking for more elegant solution, a plugin if possible. Thanks.

Comment: @Mahesh, tokenfield is very much like select2 jquery plugin. It is good to select from a list of items. But in my case, I just want to have the option to search the news or search the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its a little jquery job no plugin needed here is the code.

Just create a textbox and a div with two lines which will show in input click and then change text of that li's with the text change in textbox and here is the result : http://codepen.io/yudircks/pen/Raxabd.

*Here is the used code below*

**HTML**

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="search_cont">
  <input type="text">
  <div class="result_optins">
    <ul>
      <li><span></span>-Search news</li>
      <li><span></span>-Search the web</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  font-family:arial;
}
.search_cont input{
  width:300px;
  height:30px;
  padding:10px;
}
.search_cont .result_optins{
  width:300px;
  display:none;
}
.search_cont .result_optins ul{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.search_cont .result_optins ul li{
  list-style:none;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid #999;
  color:#aaa;
}
.search_cont .result_optins ul li span{
  color:#777
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.result_optins').show();
  });
  $('.result_optins').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  })
  $('input').on('input propertychange', function(e){
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    $('.result_optins ul li').each(function(){
        $(this).find('span').text(inputVal);
    })
  });
  $(document).on('click', function(){
    $('.result_optins').hide();
  })
})
```